# Cut off decimal numbers to 2 places but should NOT round it using ceil neither floor

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have a problem involving `number_format` in PHP, my code looks like this,

```
number_format($my_number_with_decimal, 2, '.', ', ');
```

however if I will have a number such as this `111.115` it will transform to `111.12` which is NOT what I wanted to display since it obviously rounded off the decimal numbers. Is there a workaround wherein I can limit the decimal numbers to 2 and at the same time it will not be rounded UP or DOWN ? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could still use floor (because you want to make even 111.119 round down to 111.11). Just multiply your number by 100, floor it, and divide it by 100 again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is logically impossible:

```
 11.11 <= 11.115 <= 11.12
```

Truncating `11.115` to `11.11` is rounding down, no matter how you look at it.

Comment: no. op wants to shorten/truncate the values without changing their values, which is impossible.

Comment: Yeah. As soon as I posted that, I realized I over thought it. ;) Which is why it disappeared just as quickly. =P

Comment: So, can't I do anything about my problem? I don't want to change the value of my number but if and only if my number has decimal points greater than 2, I want to CUT it into TWO(2) decimal points. I just want to cut it down to decimal points.

Comment: so use string operations. figure out where the 3rd+ decimals are and lop them off. but note that this is EXACTLY equivalent to an unconditional "round down" operation. You're removing precision from your values, which also CHANGES the values.

Comment: @MarcB, That's also what I am thinking, however in my case, the precision of the value of the number is incorrect especially when dealing with large numbers. That is why as much as possible, I will only cut it off up to two(2) decimals only.

Comment: @MarcB I chose to accept this answer since it also suggested an alternative in solving the problem. Thanks man, I solved it. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to keep only the first 2 digits, just do:

```
floor($my_number_with_decimal * 100) / 100;
```

This is equivalent to rounding down.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how many integers there are?
Presuming you do, you could cut it off by slicing it. Say for example with your number in integer format:

```
$numberWithDecimal = (string)$numberWithDecimal;
$numberWithDecimal = substr($numberWithDecimal, 0, 5);
$numberWithDecimal = (int)$numberWithDecimal;
```

If the number is already in string format you can just do:

```
$numberWithDecimal = substr($numberWithDecimal, 0, 5);
```

This might not be the best or cleanest, and it isn't tested but I hope I help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `floor()`
You can have this UDF:

```
function mine($num,$n=0){    //$n is number of decimal places
     return (floor($num*(pow(10,$n)))*pow(10,$n));
}
```

And call it:
`mine(111.115,2);`
which should return `111.11`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Marc B pointed out, truncating equals to a `floor`. So you can use simple math to floor to a specific number of digits:

```
echo floor($input * 100) / 100;
```

Keep in mind that `floor` is based on float values which arent very acurate. You may get strange results on vera large numbers. the `bc` family of functions can do floating point maths without rounding or flooring troubles!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

---

this is a floor function that uses bc functions. Try it if you have problems with floor.

```
function floor($number, $prec = 0) {
    $number = $number * pow(10,$prec);
    $number = bcdiv($number, pow(10,$prec), $prec);
    return $number;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php

Answer (score 0):

The ugly way:

```
$number = 111.115;
preg_match('/([^.]*\.\d{0,2})/', $number, $match);
echo number_format($match[1], 2, '.', ',');
```